# Display Bootstrap 4 active tab in 2 sections

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap v4.5.3, I'm trying to display an active tab in 2 sections, I searched for a better way to do this but I can't solve it so, could you please help with this?

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
 

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="row nogutters tab-content">
<div class="col mr-2 bg-secondary text-white">
  <div class="col tab-pane fade show active" id="home"role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> Home-1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile-1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact-1</div>
</div>
<div class="col mr-2 bg-secondary text-white">
  <div class="col tab-pane fade show active" id="home"role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> Home-2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile-2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact-2</div>
</div>
</div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` I'm trying to display an active tab in 2 sections` can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @Gass I need to render the active class in two sections instead of one so when the user clicks on the home it should be rendered in these two sections instead of one

Comment: So, when I click on profile you want to see home-2 change to profile-1? and so forth?

Comment: @Gass Yes, I need to duplicate the active tab so it displayed in two div's instead of one

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has to be done manually using jQuery and the events given by Bootstrap 4.

So mainly what I'm doing here is getting the data of the target element and the previous clicked tab element and doing multiple conditions to achieve the desired behaviour.

You can see the bootstrap event at the bottom of this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  
  let target = e.target // newly activated tab
  let previous = e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
    
  if(target.id === "profile-tab"){
  
    // Remove active class from previous elements
    if(previous.id === "home-tab"){  
      
      $('#home1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#home2').removeClass('show active') 
    }
    else{
      $('#contact1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#contact2').removeClass('show active')
    }
    
    // Add active class to target elements
    $('#profile1').addClass('show active')
    $('#profile2').addClass('show active')
  
  }  
    
  if(target.id === "contact-tab"){
  
    // Remove active class from previous elements
    if(previous.id === "home-tab"){  
      
      $('#home1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#home2').removeClass('show active')
    }
    else{
      $('#profile1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#profile2').removeClass('show active')
    }
    
    // Add active class to target elements
    $('#contact1').addClass('show active')
    $('#contact2').addClass('show active')
  
  }    
  
  if(target.id === "home-tab"){
  
    // Remove active class from previous elements
    if(previous.id === "home-tab"){  
      
      $('#contact1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#contact2').removeClass('show active')
    }
    else{
      $('#profile1').removeClass('show active')
      $('#profile2').removeClass('show active')
    }
    
    // Add active class to target elements
    $('#home1').addClass('show active')
    $('#home2').addClass('show active')
  
  }    
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="row nogutters tab-content">

  <div class="col mr-2 bg-secondary text-white">
    <div class="col tab-pane fade show active" id="home1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> Home-1</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile-1</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact-1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col mr-2 bg-secondary text-white">
    <div class="col tab-pane fade show active" id="home2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> Home-2</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile-2</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact-2</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```